# PC asks to format Veracrypt Volume

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, mbr, gpt

I have a Veracrypt encrypted non-system partition on an external hard drive. The hard drive is GPT-based. On my previous MBR-based hard drives, I used Diskpart and the command `SET ID=64` to prevent windows asking for format. I cannot do so with GPT-based drive. Also, converting it to MBR is not an option as it is a 4TB hard disk. If anyone can come up with a solution, it'd be greatly helpful for me.
As an aside, I used to assign drive letter to a volume using assign command. As far as I remember, the volume usually mounted using that letter in other computers too. Does that procedure not work with GPT?

Comment: I did not think truecrypt worked on a gpt volume....

Comment: My bad. It's actually Veracrypt. That's for pointing that out.